# Performing a simple search in MySQL db with variable amount of input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, relational-division

I have a many-to-many db with these three tables, Films, Ambiences, Films_Ambience:

```
CREATE TABLE Films (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),    
Title VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE Ambiences (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
PRIMARY KEY(id),  
ambienceName VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE Films_Ambiences (
film_id INT NOT NULL,  
ambience_id INT NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (film_id, ambience_id),  
FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES Films(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
FOREIGN KEY (ambience_id) REFERENCES Ambiences(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

I am using information from a form to search for specific films (e.g. film that is funny and scary at the same time). The form are simply 'ticks' next to given names. The information is sent by $_POST.

The problem is that I don't know how many requirements will there be. I know the maximum number that a user can choose but I cannot tell how many or which they will actually pick (I could do that by checking `isset($_POST['somethin'])` but it would be very.. monotonous if I had, for example, 20 different options. So I cannot do anything like:

```
$ambience1 = $_POST["a1"];
$ambience2 = $_POST["a2"];
$ambience3 = $_POST["a2"];
...
...
...
```

and:

```
SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(ambienceName SEPARATOR ' ') AS ambiences
FROM Films AS f 
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa ON f.id = fa.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a ON a.id = fa.ambience_id
GROUP BY Title
HAVING (ambiences LIKE '%$ambience1%' AND ambiences LIKE '%$ambience2%' AND ...
```

I'm not even sure where to start. Can I do it with SQL or rather PHP?

Here's an **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23afc/19)** if U like.

Comment: Your query isn't correct even if you do know the number of ambiences. A single ambience can't match both sad and funny at the same time.

Comment: And there's no column `a.ambiences`.

Comment: What I meant was just ambiences, I believe. Edited.

Comment: I added the `relational-division` tag, because that's the type of SQL problem you're describing.  I had to remove the `form` tag because of StackOverflow's limit of five tags per question.

Comment: You are most likely vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)...

Comment: The `WHERE` clause can't refer to aliases in the `SELECT` clause, you have to use `HAVING` for that.

Comment: @Barmar right, Edited, thx.
@MarcB I know, thx, but that's not the problem here ;) I could always use `mysqli__real_escape_string($var)` I believe.
@BillKarwin Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using keyword search predicates `LIKE '%pattern%'` is a [sure way to cause poor performance](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql), because it forces a table-scan.

The best way to do a [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) query, that is to match only movies where all three criteria are matched, is to find individual rows for each of the criteria, and then JOIN them together.

```
SELECT f.*, CONCAT_WS(' ', a1.ambienceName, a2.ambienceName, a3.ambienceName) AS ambiences
FROM Films AS f 
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa1 ON f.id = fa1.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a1 ON a1.id = fa1.ambience_id
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa2 ON f.id = fa2.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a2 ON a2.id = fa2.ambience_id
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa3 ON f.id = fa3.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a3 ON a3.id = fa3.ambience_id
WHERE (a1.ambienceName, a2.ambienceName, a3.ambienceName) = (?, ?, ?);
```

You'll need an additional `JOIN` to `Films_Ambiences` and `Ambiences` *for each search term*.

You should have an index on `ambienceName`, and then all three lookups will be more efficient.

```
ALTER TABLE Ambiences ADD KEY (ambienceName);
```

I compared different solutions for relational division in a recent presentation:

- Slides: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized
- Webinar recording: http://www.percona.com/webinars/mysql-query-patterns-optimized

---

Re your comment:

> Is there a way to alter this query so that it also displays the rest of the ambiences after the criteria are found?

Yes, but you have to join one more time to get the full set of ambiences for the film:

```
SELECT f.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a_all.ambienceName) AS ambiences
FROM Films AS f 
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa1 ON f.id = fa1.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a1 ON a1.id = fa1.ambience_id
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa2 ON f.id = fa2.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a2 ON a2.id = fa2.ambience_id
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa3 ON f.id = fa3.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a3 ON a3.id = fa3.ambience_id
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences AS fa_all ON f.id = fa_all.film_id
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a_all ON a_all.id = fa_all.ambience_id
WHERE (a1.ambienceName, a2.ambienceName, a3.ambienceName) = (?, ?, ?)
GROUP BY f.id;
```

> is there a way to alter this query so that the result are only films that have the ambiences required but no more?

The query above should do that.

---

> What the query does, I think, is to look for films that include the given ambiences (so it also find films that have more ambiences).

Right, the query does not match a film unless it matches all three ambiences in the search criteria.  But the film may have other ambiences beyond those in the search criteria, and all of the film's ambiences (those in the search criteria plus others) are collected as `GROUP_CONCAT(a_all.ambienceName)`.

I tested this example:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Ambiences (ambienceName) 
 VALUES ('funny'), ('scary'), ('1950s'), ('London'), ('bank'), ('crime'), ('stupid');
mysql> INSERT INTO Films (title) 
 VALUES ('Mary Poppins'), ('Heist'), ('Scary Movie'), ('Godzilla'), ('Signs');
mysql> INSERT INTO Films_Ambiences 
 VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(1,5), (2,1),(2,2),(2,5),(2,6), (3,1),(3,2),(3,7), (4,2),(4,3), (5,2),(5,7);

mysql> SELECT f.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a_all.ambienceName) AS ambiences 
 FROM Films AS f  
 INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa1 ON f.id = fa1.film_id            
 INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a1 ON a1.id = fa1.ambience_id 
 INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa2 ON f.id = fa2.film_id            
 INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a2 ON a2.id = fa2.ambience_id 
 INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa3 ON f.id = fa3.film_id            
 INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a3 ON a3.id = fa3.ambience_id 
 INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences AS fa_all ON f.id = fa_all.film_id 
 INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a_all ON a_all.id = fa_all.ambience_id 
 WHERE (a1.ambienceName, a2.ambienceName, a3.ambienceName) = ('funny','scary','bank') 
 GROUP BY f.id;
+----+--------------+-------------------------+
| id | Title        | ambiences               |
+----+--------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Mary Poppins | funny,scary,London,bank |
|  2 | Heist        | funny,scary,bank,crime  |
+----+--------------+-------------------------+
```

By the way, here's the EXPLAIN showing usage of indexes:

```
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type   | possible_keys        | key          | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a1     | ref    | PRIMARY,ambienceName | ambienceName | 258     | const                       |    1 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a2     | ref    | PRIMARY,ambienceName | ambienceName | 258     | const                       |    1 | Using where; Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a3     | ref    | PRIMARY,ambienceName | ambienceName | 258     | const                       |    1 | Using where; Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fa1    | ref    | PRIMARY,ambience_id  | ambience_id  | 4       | test.a1.id                  |    1 | Using index                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f      | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY      | 4       | test.fa1.film_id            |    1 | NULL                                                      |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fa2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ambience_id  | PRIMARY      | 8       | test.fa1.film_id,test.a2.id |    1 | Using index                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fa3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ambience_id  | PRIMARY      | 8       | test.fa1.film_id,test.a3.id |    1 | Using index                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fa_all | ref    | PRIMARY,ambience_id  | PRIMARY      | 4       | test.fa1.film_id            |    1 | Using index                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a_all  | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY      | 4       | test.fa_all.ambience_id     |    1 | NULL                                                      |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

> I have a film1 which is scary, funny, stupid. When I search for a film which is only scary, stupid I will get film1 anyway. What if I dont want that?

Oh, okay, I totally didn't understand that was what you meant, and it's an unusual requirement in these types of problems.

Here's a solution:

```
mysql> SELECT f.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a_all.ambienceName) AS ambiences
 FROM Films AS f
 INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa1 ON f.id = fa1.film_id
 INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a1 ON a1.id = fa1.ambience_id
 INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa2 ON f.id = fa2.film_id
 INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a2 ON a2.id = fa2.ambience_id
 INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences AS fa_all ON f.id = fa_all.film_id
 WHERE (a1.ambienceName, a2.ambienceName) = ('scary','stupid')
 GROUP BY f.id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | Title | ambiences    |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  5 | Signs | scary,stupid |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

There's no need to join to `a_all` in this case, because we don't need the list of ambiences names, we only need the count of ambiences, which we can get just by joining to `fa_all`.

Comment: The problem here, however, is that a film might have more ambiences than only those required. In such case, I am not displaying them. Is there a way to alter this query so that it also displays the rest of the ambiences after the criteria are found? Alternatively, is there a way to alter this query so that the result  are only films that have the ambiences required but no more?

Comment: thanks for the 1st part. But concerning the 2nd one: What the query does, I think,  is to look for films that include the given ambiences (so it also finds films that have more ambiences). Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: To exemplify what I mean:
I have a `film1` which is `scary, funny, stupid`.
When I search for a film which is only `scary, stupid` I will get `film1` anyway. What if I dont want that?

Comment: Yes, I understand that :D. So my question was: Is there an easy way to find movies that have no other ambiences than the specified ones?

Comment: And by the way I'm sorry if I'm taking your time for things which may seem easy.

Comment: Perfect! Well it might be useful if I want to give the user a choice: search for exact matches or search for similar films :). Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use PHP to build your SQL, something like this:

```
$ambienceWhere = '1=1 ';
for ($i=0;$i<NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_AMBIENCES;$i++) {
  if (isset($_POST['a' . $i])) { // or another criteria to avoid processing this one       
    $ambienceWhere .= ' AND '; 
    $ambienceWhere .= ' a.ambiences LIKE \'%' . $_POST['a'. $i] '%\' ';
  }
}
$query = 'SELECT ....... WHERE ('. $ambienceWhere.') .....'
```

Comment: This seems like a solution But wouldn't it have a negative impact on performance?

Comment: As noted by other answers, the LIKE query could be very expensive, though the PHP loop is not very expensive, unless you have way too much NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_AMBIENCES, but i doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Your form should have the ambiences in an array of elements, perhaps a multiple select. This will then turn into an array in PHP, `$_POST['ambience'][]`. Then you can write:

```
$ambience_query = implode(' AND ', array_map(function($a) use($mysqli) {
    return "'%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $a) . "'";
}, $_POST['ambience']));

$query = "SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(ambienceName SEPARATOR ' ') AS ambiences
FROM FROM Films AS f 
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa ON f.id = fa.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a ON a.id = fa.ambience_id
GROUP BY Title
HAVING $ambience_query";
```

This is a very expensive query. It will have to calculate the `GROUP_CONCAT(ambienceName)` of every film in the database before filtering down to the ones you want. it would be better to structure the query like:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM Films f
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences fa1 ON f.id = fa1.film_id
INNER JOIN Ambiences a1 ON a1.id = f1.ambience_id
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences fa2 ON f.id = fa2.film_id
INNER JOIN Ambiences a2 ON a2.id = f2.ambience_id
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences fa3 ON f.id = fa3.film_id
INNER JOIN Ambiences a3 ON a3.id = f3.ambience_id
...
WHERE a1.ambienceName = '$_POST[ambience][1]'
  AND a2.ambienceName = '$_POST[ambience][2]'
  AND a3.ambienceName = '$_POST[ambience][3]'
  ...
```

You can use loops similar to the above or Josejulio's answer to construct this query.

Comment: So if $_POST['ambience'] has an empty element it will just search the table column for '%'?

Comment: You should filter those out before the loop.

Comment: I fixed the second version. It doesn't need to use `LIKE`, it can do exact matches.

Comment: Please don't show interpolation of `$_POST` variables directly into SQL, even for example purposes.

Comment: @BillKarwin I already showed the proper way in the first example, I didn't feel like writing all that out for the second one. I told him to use the same technique. Your method with placeholders won't work, either, since you can't prepare a statement with a variable number of parameters.

Comment: I don't have a variable number of parameters in my example, I have three parameters.  By the same argument, your solution wouldn't work because SQL doesn't support a variable number of joins.  In both your solution and mine, one would have to write code to build the SQL query dynamically based on the number of criteria input from the form.